# How can I downgrade a PPA package to the official version?

Tags: ppa, downgrade, checkbox

I have `ppa:cr3/ppa` in my sources list. It upgrades my `checkbox`, `checkbox-gtk`, and `checkbox-qt` packages to version `0.14~ppa6.12.04`. And now I have problems with updating my system, and sometimes critical system errors.

I tried to use `ppa-purge` to downgrade them - it didn't work. I tried to delete them from synaptic - it wants to delete `ubuntu-desktop` with them.

When I try to update system I'm getting an error:

```
 checkbox
 checkbox-gtk
 checkbox-qt
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Deleting ubuntu-desktop shouldn't be a problem. We can reinstall them later on.. It's a meta package at best.

Comment: I recommend adding the output of `ppa-purge` to your question. (You can run it again to get the error output, if you no longer have it up.)

Comment: I can't do it... to much of characters....

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to force version for those packages, setting them to use the official repository one doing a click on each of them in synaptic, then package menu -> force version...

Once you set them back, feel free to remove third party repos and upgrade safely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For checkbox-gtk and checkbox-qt it works. But checkbox is remaining 0.14~ppa6 :( I am getting the same error message.

Comment: checkbox version in official 12.04 repos is 0.13.7. Try forcing it manually with `sudo apt-get install checkbox=0.13.7`

Comment: I have purged all of them with ubuntu-desktop package ... And just install them again . Everything is working, thank you.